# multiple list generation from a list based on condition in python

Tags: python, loops, lambda, list-comprehension

I have a Pandas series (which could be a list, this is not very important) of lists which contains (to simplify, but that could also be letters of words) positive and negative number,
such as

```
0 [12,-13,0,6]  
1 [2,-3,8,233]  
2 [0,6,8,3]
```

for each of these, i want to fill a row in a three columns data frame, with a list of all positive values, a list of all negative values, and a list of all values comprised in some interval. Such as:

```
 [[12,6],[-13],[0,6]]   
 [[2,8,233],[-3],[2,8]]   
 [[6,8,3],[],[6,8,3]]
```

What I first thought was using a list comprehension to generate a list of triadic lists of lists, which would be converted using pd.DataFrame to the right form.
This was because i don't want to loop over the list of lists 3 times to apply each time a new choice heuristics, feels slow and dull.

But the problem is that I can't actually generate well the lists of the triad [[positive],[negative], [interval]].
I was using a syntax like

```
[[[positivelist.extend(number)],[negativelist], [intervalist.extend(number)]]\
```

for listofnumbers in listoflists for number in listofnumbers\
 if number>0 else [positivelist],[negativelist.extend(number)], [intervalist.extend(number)]]

but let be honest, this is unreadable, and anyway it doesn't do what I want since extend yields none.
So how could I go about that without looping three times (I could have many millions elements in the list of lists, and in the sublists, and I might want to apply more complexe formulae to these numbers, too, it is a first approach)?

I thought about using functional programming, map/lambda; but it is unpythonic. The catch is: what in python may help to do it right?

My guess would be something as:

```
newlistoflist=[]
for list in lists:
     positive=[]
     negative=[]
     interval=[]
     for element in list:
         positive.extend(element) if element>0
         negative.extend(element) if element<0
         interval.extend(element) if n<element<m
     triad=[positive, negative,interval]
 newlistoflist.append(triad)
```

what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
import numpy
l = [[12,-13,0,6], [2,-3,8,233], [0,6,8,3]]
l = numpy.array([x for e in l for x in e])
positive = l[l>0]
negative = l[l<0]
n,m = 1,5
interval = l[((l>n) & (l<m))]
print positive, negative, interval
```

Output: `[ 12   6   2   8 233   6   8   3] [-13  -3] [2 3]`

**Edit**: Triad version:

```
import numpy
l = numpy.array([[12,-13,0,6], [2,-3,8,233], [0,6,8,3]])
n,m = 1,5
triad = numpy.array([[e[e>0], e[e<0], e[((e>n) & (e<m))]] for e in l])
print triad
```

Output:

```
[[array([12,  6]) array([-13]) array([], dtype=int64)]
 [array([  2,   8, 233]) array([-3]) array([2])]
 [array([6, 8, 3]) array([], dtype=int64) array([3])]]
```

Comment: That's a start but it doesn't do what I want. With your exemple, for each list, I'd like a triad :
[[12,6],[-13],[0,6]]
[[2,8,233],[-3],[2,8]]
[[6,8,3],[],[6,8,3]]

Comment: Can you give `n,m`for interval?

Comment: @AndoJurai: If you change `n,m` values it should be it.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to use the same principle on list containing words instead? I guess that the masking use may be reproduced (and eventually transposed to pandas, which would be more practical for me) but I can't be sure.

Comment: You can use the same principle e.g. `l = numpy.array([['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'], ['theta', 'epislon', 'zeta'], ['delta', 'sigma', 'omega']], dtype=str)` then
`triad = numpy.array([[e[e>'a'], e[e<'h'], e[((e>'a') & (e<'g'))]] for e in l])`